# Golang template with switch & ForEach

Tags: templates, go

I need to create **bash.sh** file from golang program
which should do the following:

Create **ForEach** loop on dependencies and read the type and according to type 
print different echo message (commands) I need it to work with **switch**
on the `type` of the dependency with Golang

e.g. something like following

For each dependency entry add the type message of echo

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in $(dependencies.type) 
  echo $runner  //from type 
done
```

what I did is the following which doesn't work

1. The idea that for dependencies type **"runner1"**(see the type property value in dependency struct instance) I need to run **several commands** and for **"runner2"** I need to run **several different commands**
2. And those commands (like echo api1 for runner1 etc )above should be written in the bash.script that I need to create from the template

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "text/template"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "os"
)

type File struct {
    TypeVersion string `yaml:"_type-version"`
    Dependency  []Dependency
}

type Dependency struct {
    Name    string
    Type    string
    CWD     string
    Install []Install
}

type Install map[string]string

var data = `
_type-version: "1.0.0"
dependency:
  - name: ui
    type: runner
    cwd: /ui
    install:
       - name: api

  - name: ui2
    type: runner2
    cwd: /ui2
    install:
       - name: api2

`

func main() {
    f := File{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }

    d, err := yaml.Marshal(&f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t dump:\n%s\n\n", string(d))

    wd, _ := os.Getwd()

    newfile, err := os.Create(wd + "/" + "bash.sh") // Truncates if file already exists
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Failed to create file: %s , %s", wd+"/"+"bash.sh", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(newfile)

    const File = `
#!/bin/bash
{{.dependency}},
{{if .Type runner2}}
 echo "type is runner2"
{{- else}}
echo "type is %S"
{{- end}}
{{end}}
`

    t := template.Must(template.New("bash.sh").Parse(File))

    for _, r := range f.Dependency {
        err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, r)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("executing template:", err)
        }
    }

}
```

**update**

For example

lets say i’ve map like following and the dependencies struct should work with the API struct to know which command to run for each type value

```
API := map[string]string {
{
“runner1” : “api1”,
},
{
“runner2” : “api2”,
}
}
```

This is how should the script look like at the end

```
#bin/bash

// in context of dep1
echo runner1
submitting api1


// in context of dep2
echo runner2
submitting api2
```

Comment: You might want to use a session for this, because what you have done here wouldn't work multi-user either.

Comment: Have a look here, https://github.com/expressjs/session  once you have a session handler, you can just do things like ->  `req.session.aaa = req.body.aa`..

Comment: @JennyHilton Are you looking for something like this? https://play.golang.org/p/v65jr0Hr5v2

Comment: @mkopriva - Thanks, I need two things 1. generate bash.script with the results of the template 2.  for each entry (type of dependencies) I need to call like echo  api1 and for the second echo api2 , this is in the install object.

Comment: @mkopriva - and it should have `switch` like statment  , like if its `runner1` call to `api1` and if it `runner2` call to` api2`

Comment: @mkopriva - The idea that for dep type `"runner1"` I need to run several commands and for `"runner2"` I need to run `several different commands `

Comment: @JennyHilton I'm still not 100% sure what you mean, but you could have a switch statement inside a method defined on the `Dependency` type, and based on the value of the `Type` field the method would return the correct command name and command arguments... Or what you can do to clarify, given the example yaml file, provide the exact bash script you would like the Go program to generate.

Comment: @mkopriva - please see my update, let me know if its more clear now

Comment: @JennyHilton https://play.golang.org/p/jx_V_62Qu47 ?

Comment: @mkopriva - Much better, i'll check it deeply and let you know. i've currently 2 questions 1. how should I generate a file from the template output 2. assume that I've two structs `API` and `Dependency` (see my update) , how it should work then ?

Comment: @mkopriva - btw, you can put it as answer ... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169086/discussion-between-jenny-hilton-and-mkopriva).

Comment: Please read through the docs here: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/ All of your template needs are explained there in clear detail. Please understand that it is important that you put some work into solving the problem yourself. I'm here because i'm trying to help and learn, I'm not here to work for free.

Comment: @mkopriva - Well, I did it but some things are not clear to me 100% therefore I put bounty of 100 points...thanks anyhow...

Answer (score 3):

Some minimal changes to get to working for the above are here:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "text/template"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "os"
)

type File struct {
    TypeVersion string `yaml:"_type-version"`
    Dependency  []Dependency
}

type Dependency struct {
    Name    string
    Type    string
    CWD     string
    Install []Install
}

type Install map[string]string

var data = `
_type-version: "1.0.0"
dependency:
  - name: ui
    type: runner
    cwd: /ui
    install:
       - name: api

  - name: ui2
    type: runner2
    cwd: /ui2
    install:
       - name: api2

`

func main() {
    f := File{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }

   const t = `
#!/bin/bash

{{range .Dependency}}
echo "type is {{.Type}}"
echo "cwd is {{.CWD}}"
{{range .Install}}
echo "install {{.name}}"
{{end}}
{{end}}
`

    tt := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(t))
    err = tt.Execute(os.Stdout, f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("executing template:", err)
    }
}
```

This produces

```
$ go run main.go 

#!/bin/bash


echo "type is runner"
echo "cwd is /ui"

echo "install api"


echo "type is runner2"
echo "cwd is /ui2"

echo "install api2"
```

The key change is to let the template do the work- use the range function on the Dependency array, and then again on the Install array, to traverse the data structure.

The other change is just to write to stdout, rather than to a file. If it is desirable to turn this into a script, just pipe it to a file.

More broadly, I think there is a tension in the data model around ownership of the install steps. Are the install steps fixed for each runner type? Or may they vary? If they are fixed, then having a map[string][string] of runner type to array of install steps probably makes sense, which would then relieve the Dependency object of having a copy of install steps.

I also wonder about the YAML- is it a source of truth? Or is it derivative? If derivative, perhaps it is unnecessary. Probably better to have the go program interrogate the actual source of truth and generate a script.

In any event, I hope that's helpful.

Comment: I wasnt able to test it depely , i'll give you the points and I've sevrel of question hopefully you can assist ...thanks

Comment: @jennyhilton sure, happy to chat further.