# How to change the format of log output in logrus?

Tags: go, logging

I use Go logrus and I need to change the format of the output message. I tried several things without success.

What I need is format like this with formatter of logrus

`[error]: datetime -  message`

What I've tried without success is this

```golang
     logger := &logrus.Logger{
            Out:   os.Stderr,
            Level: level,
            Formatter: &logrus.TextFormatter{
                DisableColors: true,
                TimestampFormat : "2006-01-02 15:04:05",
                FullTimestamp:true,
    
            },
        }
```

This produce the following

```
    time="2018-02-25 10:42:20" level=error msg="Starting Process"
```

And I want it to be

```
    [INFO]:2018-02-25 10:42:20 - Starting Process
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### Standard logrus-prefixed-formater usage

To achieve this you need to make your own `TextFormater` which will satisfy logrus `Formatter` interface. Then when you create your own formater you pass it on logrus struct initialization. Other way arround and close to what you wanna achieve is this formater https://github.com/x-cray/logrus-prefixed-formatter . Based on this formater you can create your own.

In your case you need to use like that

```
logger := &logrus.Logger{
        Out:   os.Stderr,
        Level: logrus.DebugLevel,
        Formatter: &prefixed.TextFormatter{
            DisableColors: true,
            TimestampFormat : "2006-01-02 15:04:05",
            FullTimestamp:true,
            ForceFormatting: true,
        },
    }
```

---

#### Customized output of logrus-prefixed-formater

Link to gist to use copy of `logrus-prefixed-formatter` with changed format
https://gist.github.com/t-tomalak/146e4269460fc63d6938264bb5aaa1db

I leave this option if u in the end wanna use it, as in this version you have exact format you want, coloring, and other features available in standard formatter

---

#### Custom formatter

Third option is to use package create by me https://github.com/t-tomalak/logrus-easy-formatter. It provide simple option to format output as you want and is it only purpose. I removed not necessary options which probably you wouldn't use.

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "github.com/t-tomalak/logrus-easy-formatter"
)

func main() {
    logger := &logrus.Logger{
        Out:   os.Stderr,
        Level: logrus.DebugLevel,
        Formatter: &easy.Formatter{
            TimestampFormat: "2006-01-02 15:04:05",
            LogFormat:       "[%lvl%]: %time% - %msg%",
        },
    }

    logger.Printf("Log message")
}
```

This sample code will produce:

```
[INFO]: 2018-02-27 19:16:55 - Log message
```

Also I wanna point out that if in the future wanna change formatter there shouldn't be any problems to use i.e. default Logrus `TextFormatter/JSONFormatter`.

---

#### Customized output of logrus-prefixed-formater

If you really don't wanna copy this formatter to your project you can use my fork logrus-prefixed-formater with copy/pasted this code
https://github.com/t-tomalak/logrus-prefixed-formatter

You can use it like standard option but remember to change import to my repository in you go file

```
logger := &logrus.Logger{
        Out:   os.Stderr,
        Level: logrus.DebugLevel,
        Formatter: &prefixed.TextFormatter{
            DisableColors: true,
            TimestampFormat : "2006-01-02 15:04:05",
            FullTimestamp:true,
            ForceFormatting: true,
        },
    }
```

Comment: Thanks when using the code you provided it change the format of the message but not as I need, the [info] is missing, how it can be added ?

Comment: It prints `[2018-02-25 13:16:27] ERROR Starting Process` and I need it like `[ERROR]:2018-02-25 10:42:20 - Starting Process`

Comment: That what i said it's close to yours but if you need exact one you need to change it according to your need. Best way would be coping whole `formater.go` file and then you can change function which I added to my answer

Comment: I try to copy the function to my program after the `newlogger` function and I got lot of errors, any idea? like unresolved `*TextFormatter` etc and I import both ` "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
 "fmt"

 "github.com/x-cray/logrus-prefixed-formatter"` any idea?

Comment: You can ommit `logrus-prefixed-formatter` import and only copy whole `formater.go` file from this lib and put it somewhere in your project, and then replace in that file that function, and use it as new formater in your logrus initialization

Comment: Ok 1+, something that I miss if I copy the forammater to my project, how should I use it in my new object logger := &logrus.Logger{
 ....

Comment: It should be something like this `Formatter: &TextFormatter{` if its in the same `package` directory

Comment: I put it in new file in the package of loggers that i've and add to it  "bytes"
 "strings"
 "fmt"
 "github.com/sirupsen/logrus" and got the same errors...did you try it ?

Comment: yes, and this works https://gist.github.com/t-tomalak/146e4269460fc63d6938264bb5aaa1db what kind of error did you get?

Comment: To achieve what I need I need to copy all the `formatter.go `function ? this is crazy, are you sure there is no simple way to do it ?

Comment: Why it's crazy? If u wanna make your own formatter it's no other way arround then build your own from scratch or like I tell you copy some existing one and change according to your needs. And yeah you only need satisfy simply interface which is https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/blob/8c0189d9f6bbf301e5d055d34268156b317016af/formatter.go#L17 but then you probably need to make another methods that will be compatible with options like Timestamp format etc.

Comment: Im a bit confused :( , Can you provide step by step what should I do to use the formatter ?  thanks!

Comment: OK, there is other OS in go that can provide simply what I need ?

Comment: @JennyHilton check please if my solutiuon satisfy your needs

Comment: This should have been accepted by now. How far do you have to go?

Comment: Thanks, i've checked it but there is two issue, 1. There are missing colors 2. the messages are concatenated and the second message is not in the next line ...

Comment: Added option with fork of logrus-prefixed-formatter library @JennyHilton

Comment: @ttomalak - sorry but fork is not an option in our case :( , any other direction /idea?

Comment: @ttomalak - can you assist please ?

Comment: @JennyHilton I gave you all posiblle solution. I don't understand why u can't use fork. If there is problem that is my fork you can make your own. Also copying this formater into the project is ideal solution in your situation. Other way would be build own whole logger

Comment: @ttomalak - what do you mean by "opying this formater into the project is ideal solution" which of your suggestion is it ?

Comment: @JennyHilton second one

Comment: @ttomalak sorry for the delay, do you mean Custom formatter or the giant :) gist which you have created?

Comment: can you confirm ?

Comment: @JennyHilton I mean that huge gist which is the copy of logrus-prefixed-formatter with changed output

Comment: @ttomalak - I've opend new message with bounty, please see if you can assist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511312/golang-template-with-switch-on-objcts thanks

Comment: Why couldn't they ship multiple default layouts? I swear. Sometimes developers, *sigh*!

Answer (score 8):

I guess I am quite late to this, but recently I was also struggling to get this logging message format customized and I was hoping to get this done preferably in a simpler way. Coming from Python, this wasn't really as straight forward as I though it to be and logrus documentation also isn't very clear on this.

So I had to go through their source code to actually get this done. Here is my code for the same.

```
type myFormatter struct {
    log.TextFormatter
}

func (f *myFormatter) Format(entry *log.Entry) ([]byte, error) {
// this whole mess of dealing with ansi color codes is required if you want the colored output otherwise you will lose colors in the log levels
    var levelColor int
    switch entry.Level {
    case log.DebugLevel, log.TraceLevel:
        levelColor = 31 // gray
    case log.WarnLevel:
        levelColor = 33 // yellow
    case log.ErrorLevel, log.FatalLevel, log.PanicLevel:
        levelColor = 31 // red
    default:
        levelColor = 36 // blue
    }
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("[%s] - \x1b[%dm%s\x1b[0m - %s\n", entry.Time.Format(f.TimestampFormat), levelColor, strings.ToUpper(entry.Level.String()), entry.Message)), nil
}

func main() {
    f, _ := os.OpenFile("log.txt", os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0777)
    logger := &log.Logger{
        Out:   io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, f),
        Level: log.InfoLevel,
        Formatter: &myFormatter{log.TextFormatter{
            FullTimestamp:          true,
            TimestampFormat:        "2006-01-02 15:04:05",
            ForceColors:            true,
            DisableLevelTruncation: true,
        },
        },
    }
    logger.Info("Info message")
    logger.Warning("Warning message")
```

Here is the output

```
± go run main.go                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <<<
[2019-05-13 18:10:34] - INFO - Info message
[2019-05-13 18:10:34] - WARNING - Warning message
```

PS:  I am very new to this, so if you guys there can be a better neat way of doing this, please do share.

Answer (score 4):

I adopted this code from https://github.com/x-cray/logrus-prefixed-formatter/blob/master/formatter.go.
I created an own formatter struct and implementend an own Format function of the logrus formatter interface.
I you only need a text output without color, this might be a simple solution.

```
// adopted from https://github.com/x-cray/logrus-prefixed-formatter/blob/master/formatter.go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

type LogFormat struct {
    TimestampFormat string
}

func (f *LogFormat) Format(entry *logrus.Entry) ([]byte, error) {
    var b *bytes.Buffer

    if entry.Buffer != nil {
        b = entry.Buffer
    } else {
        b = &bytes.Buffer{}
    }

    b.WriteByte('[')
    b.WriteString(strings.ToUpper(entry.Level.String()))
    b.WriteString("]:")
    b.WriteString(entry.Time.Format(f.TimestampFormat))

    if entry.Message != "" {
        b.WriteString(" - ")
        b.WriteString(entry.Message)
    }

    if len(entry.Data) > 0 {
        b.WriteString(" || ")
    }
    for key, value := range entry.Data {
        b.WriteString(key)
        b.WriteByte('=')
        b.WriteByte('{')
        fmt.Fprint(b, value)
        b.WriteString("}, ")
    }

    b.WriteByte('\n')
    return b.Bytes(), nil
}

func main() {
    formatter := LogFormat{}
    formatter.TimestampFormat = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"

    logrus.SetFormatter(&formatter)
    log.SetOutput(os.Stderr)

    logrus.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
        "animal": "walrus",
        "size":   10,
    }).Info("A group of walrus emerges from the ocean")
    logrus.Info("ugh ugh ugh ugh")
}
```

Comment: I want to test it and I've errors in formatter := format.LogFormat{}
 formatter.TimestampFormat = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"

Comment: Oh, yeah my bad, i had the formatter in an own package, thats why i mixed it up. Should be fixed now.

Comment: I use the new logger object like this, can you adopt your code to it please? ` logger := &logrus.Logger{
        Out:   os.Stderr,
        Level: level,
        Formatter: &logrus.TextFormatter{
            DisableColors: true,
            TimestampFormat : "2006-01-02 15:04:05",
            FullTimestamp:true,

        },
    }`

Comment: Ok, I was able to make it work 1+ ...but the problem is that all the colors and functionality is missing, can you adopt it ?

Comment: https://github.com/x-cray/logrus-prefixed-formatter/blob/master/formatter.go
You should take a look at this and change the Format function.

Comment: can you assist to achieve the full capabilities ? I just want to change the format message and not change the default provided options... therefore I put bounty for this ... thanks

Comment: HI, any idea how to add the missing functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

As the previous responders said the answer here is to use a custom formatter.
When I was looking for a quick solution with a more human-readable format than default logrus' format, I came up with this formatter:

[image: nested logrus formatter]

Code and instructions are there: https://github.com/antonfisher/nested-logrus-formatter